# Format a duration of more than one day in "Number of Days, Hours, Minutes" on Libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have cells containing duration in minutes.

I do a summation of them in another cell, and applies on it the *Time* pattern `HH:MM`.

It works fine, until the sum outreaches 24 hours, where it shows me : `06:02`, but I know that it is : `1 day, 6 hours and 2 minutes`.

I've attempted a custom format, adding a `D` to it : `D HH:MM`. But it only led to a strange output : `31 06:02` (as we aren't the 31th of June today at the time I'm posting this question, but the 12th...) and it's not the `01` or `1` expected.

Do I have a way to format the duration the way I willing to, through the mean of a custom pattern ?

---

Note that I have a workaround, because I'm in great need of a solution, but you'll see that it is clumsy. I'm using a French Libreoffice version, where functions have a french name. I try to put in comment their respective names in the UK version :

With individual duration cells having a content in minutes :
`=TEMPS(0; duration_in_minutes; 0)`

Do these intermediate calculations :

```
Cell A: 1           # Number of days 
=ENT(SOMME(F2:F21)) # SUM and INT functions in English Libreoffice, I think

Cell B: 06:02       # Hours and minutes remaining, pattern 'HH:MM' applied
=(SOMME(F2:F21) - ENT(SOMME(F2:F21)))

Cell C: 6 h 02           # Format time another way.
=TEXTE($C$29;"H \h MM")  # TEXT function in English version

Cell D: 1 jour 6 h 02    # Concat them all
=CONCAT($C$30;" jour"; " ";$E$30)
```

So at the end, I have something like that : a list of individual duration, and a sum expressed in days, hours, minutes.

```
00:49
04:33
00:37
01:01
00:34
00:49
01:10
01:00
01:50
00:51
00:48
00:43
01:08
02:34
00:37
02:14
01:32
02:36
01:25
03:11
1 jour 6 h 02
```

Comment: I have not posted this as an answer as I dont know if it would be acceptable. Assuming that the sum is in cell A22, try this formula in B22: `=CONCAT(LEFT(A22,FIND(".",A22,1)-1)," jour ", REPLACE(TEXT(A22,"HH:MM"),3,1," h "))`

Answer (score 0):

Date and time values are stored as number of days, so if your sum is in cell A1 then you can use the following formula in B1:

```
=TRUNC(A1)&" days "&TEXT(A1-TRUNC(A1),"HH:MM:SS")
```

For example, if cell A1 contains `120.60278` then B1 will have:

```
120 days 14:28:00
```

Adjust strings in quotes to have desired format.